# JQuery hide multiple div of similar id when clicked outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide all the `div` with similar `id` if not clicked on any of those div's. In my code it is working only for the first div since I have use `index[0]` to fetch the id. I want to generalize it to work for all the id.

Here is the code:

```js
$(window).click(function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != $('[id^=div_]')[0].id) {
    $('[id^=div_]').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_1">One</div>
<div id="div_2">Two</div>
<div id="div_3">Three</div>
<div id="div_4">Four</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/304vkc0k/1/)

Comment: add a class, and hide by class for all.

Comment: so you don't want to hide any of the divs if they are clicked on? Is that what you're asking? Why not use a class/name instead

Comment: @A.Lau yes I want to hide them if clicked outside.

Comment: Use Array.find function

Comment: @Paddy I cannot make any changes in HTML like adding classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution here is to use a common class on all the elements. You can then use `is()` to determine if `e.target` was one of those elements and hide/show them as needed. Try this:

```js
$(window).click(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is('.div')) {
    $('.div').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_1" class="div">One</div>
<div id="div_2" class="div">Two</div>
<div id="div_3" class="div">Three</div>
<div id="div_4" class="div">Four</div>
```

> I cannot make any changes in HTML like adding classes

In that case you can check the `id` of the clicked element to see if it begins with `div_`. If not, then hide all the divs, something like this:

```js
$(window).click(function(e) {
  if (e.target.id.indexOf('div_') != 0) {
    $('[id^=div_]').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_1" class="div">One</div>
<div id="div_2" class="div">Two</div>
<div id="div_3" class="div">Three</div>
<div id="div_4" class="div">Four</div>
```

Comment: The problem is I cannot make any changes in HTML. I cannot add any class in HTML

Comment: Thanks Its working.Great solution.Never thought of it.

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can use this function

```
if(e.target.id=="" || $('[id^=div_]').filter('#'+e.target.id).length==0){
     $('[id^=div_]').hide();
  }
```

`filter` function will filter the selected div in list of `div` whoes `id` starts with div

```js
$(window).click(function(e) {
  if(e.target.id=="" || $('[id^=div_]').filter('#'+e.target.id).length==0){
     $('[id^=div_]').hide();
  }

});
```

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_1">One</div>
<div id="div_2">Two</div>
<div id="div_3">Three</div>
<div id="div_4">Four</div>
```